# Python, pandas, boolean indexer on multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

Lets consider the following pandas DataFrame:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
dic={'volume': {('CSC', Timestamp('2016-08-06 00:00:00'), 'CSCF7'): 0,
  ('CSC', Timestamp('2016-08-07 00:00:00'), 'CSCG7'): 0,
  ('CSC', Timestamp('2016-08-08 00:00:00'), 'CSCH7'): 0,
  ('DA', Timestamp('2016-08-06 00:00:00'), 'DCF7'): 0,
  ('DA', Timestamp('2016-08-07 00:00:00'), 'DCG7'): 0,
  ('DA', Timestamp('2016-08-08 00:00:00'), 'DCH7'): 0,
  ('GF', Timestamp('2016-08-06 00:00:00'), 'GFF7'): 0,
  ('GF', Timestamp('2016-08-07 00:00:00'), 'GFH7'): 0,
  ('GF', Timestamp('2016-08-08 00:00:00'), 'GFJ7'): 0}}

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

[image]

I would like to select certain rows using the boolean indexer:
here i want to select only the rows that are occuring at certain days of the week by using `dayofweek!=5`.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Using `get_level_values` on `df.index` you can

```
In [367]: df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(1).dayofweek != 5]
Out[367]:
                      volume
CSC 2016-08-07 CSCG7       0
    2016-08-08 CSCH7       0
DA  2016-08-07 DCG7        0
    2016-08-08 DCH7        0
GF  2016-08-07 GFH7        0
    2016-08-08 GFJ7        0
```

Comment: My answer was exact same. You are the fastest finger now. +1